# Can't resolve 'history/createBrowserHistory'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am having a problem using history in redux store.

> here is my store.js

```
 import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
// import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';
import reducer from './reducer'; //Import our reducer
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export const history = createHistory();
// Build the middleware for intercepting and dispatching navigation actions
const myRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
//Create our Store using createStore and the reducer as an argument.
export const store = createStore(
  reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

The error I'm having is:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/redux/store.js Module not found: Can't resolve
> 'history/createBrowserHistory' in
> '/home/salathiel/Documents/realcamuniv/src/redux'

Answer (score 2):

The way that ur trying to access history is deprecated, this is the warning

`Warning: Please use require("history").createBrowserHistory instead of require("history/createBrowserHistory"). Support for the latter will be removed in the next major release`

try this way instead

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28407309)

Comment: Sry for that, Ive added an explanation for the error now and also provided the solution but surely I'll try to comment when I don't feel that I have a clear answer  after reaching 50 reputations